# Simple bash program #2

Tags: bash

I want to write bach shell script which accepts three parameters: name of file, name of directory and a number.

Mistake should be reported if there are no three parameters or third is not greater than 0 or first parameter is not a file or second parameter is not a directory.

If everything is okay, file should be copied for third parameter times to the directory.

My code automatically prints mistake, how can I actually load these parameters, and is everything correct in my code since there are no mistakes reported? I am a beginner in this.

```
  #!/bin/bash
   if [ $# -ne 3 ]
   then 
   echo "Mistake" 
   exit 1
   fi
   if [ -f "$1" ]; then
      if [ -d "$2" ] ; then
         if [ "$3" -gt 0 ]; then
            for ((i=0;i<$3;i++));
            do
              cp "$1" / "$2"
            done
            fi
            fi
  else 
      echo "Mistake"
      exit 1
      fi
```

Comment: How are you actually running the code? Also, what do you expect your `cp` to do, because as written, it will try to copy your root file system to `$2` (which will fail, because you didn't use the `-r` option) (unless $1 happens to be `-r` and there is actually a file named `-r`, but that's a problem for another question).

Comment: The code itself is otherwise fine, if you pass the correct arguments.

Comment: @chepner I just want to copy file which is a parameter1 into the directory which is parameter2 for paramater3 times. My code automatically prints Mistake as a result, how can I actually input the parameters?

Comment: Then you don't need the `/` in the `cp` command at all; use `cp -- "$1" "$2"`. (The `--` protects against any weird file names that could be mistaken for an option supported by `cp`.) The question remains, *how* do you specify the two arguments when you run the script?

Comment: If that's the actual question, you do it the same way you provide arguments to `cp`: list them after the command name. If you run the script with `bash myScript`, then it's `bash myScript some.txt someDir 3` (However, each successive copy is just going to overwrite the previous files; you are going to have to generate specific names for each output file.)